# JVM maximum memory allocation in Windows 2007

Tags: java, jvm

I am using a computer withe following specification:
OS-Windows7 professional
Installed Memory(RAM) :8Gb
System Type: 64 bit Operating System
JVM: Java version 8 update 91(jre1.8.0_91) 64 bit version

java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b15, mixed mode)

For using one desktop application I need large JVM memory allocation. With the above specification I can set the JVM at maximum 1.5gb(1536mb) using -Xmx command.
If I am increasing the value above 1.5 GB getting the following error:
"The JVM could not be started.The main method may have thrown out an exception."

Please let me know how can I allocate more memory to th e JVM.

Answer (score 1):

The 1.5 GB limit means you are most likely using the Windows XP/32-bit version.  When this question has come up before the OP has been sure they were using the 64-bit version but on investigation found they were not.

I suggest making sure there is only one version of Java installed, the 64-bit version you want to use.

Comment: Hi , yes  I tried to uninstall the JVM 32 bit and run  the application. but the application is not getting launch without the JVM 32 bit. Can you please let me knwo how to make the application point to JVM 64 bit. p.s. I have tried -d64 optionin .vmoptions file of the application.

Comment: @RakaDutta Another possible cause if you don't have enough free memory. I would check the amount of swap space you have free.

Comment: I think the executable created of the application is pointing  to be default the 32 bit JVM (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre). How can I override the default JVM of a Executable? Setting the options in .vmoptions file is not working.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion the best way of detecting your problem is to use [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), it can detects if you're having a problem inside your vm and can monitor the status, it's simple to use and give a lot of debug. I saw at some articles that sometimes increasing too much the memory cause an error like this but I don't have a clue, try to look [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241105-The-JVM-could-not-be-started-The-main-method-may-have-thrown-an-exception) too, hope it helps.